# Hierarchical product documentation tool with meta data?

Tags: offline, document-management

I need a tool to store products and their documents and links to other products in a parts list.
E.g. an electronic box might be one product which has the following sub-products:

- Casing
- Assembled PCB
- Power cable

All of these three products consist of parts in turn - therefore the hierarchical need. Also, each product needs to have documents and files associated with it. Those files are separate and don't need to be merged automatically.

All documents should also have revision which is separate from the products revision.

It would be nice if it had integration with e.g. Git so that just committing will place it in the system as a new revision.

I would prefer windows onsite (e.g. server och local machine) not cloud. It doesn't have to be fancy just the feature above. Simple UI is okay. Best is a free open source solution but up to about 20 dollars/ user/ month is acceptable. I do not need any features for handling the insides of the documents like searching language and so on.

To conclude what I value is the structure and knowing which product revision is based on which document revisions. E.g. if I have a box and that box gets updated I need to know for the old box which documents are valid even in the future if I get one of the old box for repair.

Example of documents are:

- wiring
- parts list (for smaller parts like screws not defined in the hierarchical structure )
- description (describing the device)
- Source code
- Compiled code
- Assembly drawing
- CAD files

Comment: Do you need the casing+PCB+cable documentation to be maintained separately and then automatically merged into a single output document when needed? If yes, that sounds exactly like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture Please note that DITA is a standard, not a product, there are several competing implementations of it.

Comment: Are all documents in only one language (for instance Simplified Chinese), or do you need to manage translations too?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul. Thank you for your feedback. I have updated the question and hope that clears the question marks.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about https://componize.com but I don't think it fits your budget unfortunately.